# How to set DirContext bean for LDAP query in Came YAML DSL?

Tags: ldap, apache-camel

I try to crate a simple LDAP query in YAML DSL to be run in JBang

My `route.yaml` is following

```
- route:
    from:
      uri: timer:timer
      parameters:
        repeatCount: 1
      steps:
        - to:
            uri: ldap:dirContext
            parameters:
              base: ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org
        - log:
            message: ${body}
- beans:
    - name: dirContext
      properties:
        url: ldap://localhost:389
        userDn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
        password: admin
      type: java.util.Hashtable
```

If I try to run it I get following error

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial
```

How can I correctly set the dirContext?

Answer (score 0):

The `camel-ldap` component uses older tech with JNDI to search with LDAP. This works when you use JavaEE based application servers like WebLogic, JBoss EAP, etc.

Since you run this standalone with JBang then you do not have a JNDI server, and you can instead use `camel-spring-ldap` which is a more *free* component.

PS: What LDAP server you have running on `localhost:389` may also provide the JNDI server, and then you need to setup that ENV variable to point to it. And if needed to have client JARs on the classpath.

Comment: My target LDAP is Window Server 2016 AD but I am testing at OpenLDAP on my local machine. My POC is on https://github.com/jirmed/ldap-poc. In folder ldap there is a docker-compose.yaml that I use to run the OpenLDAP server. I try to create a simple route in YAML that should run in JBang and that query LDAP with custom filter and return selected attributes. I did some attemts with spring-ldap but I have not moved wery far. See my other thread on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072376/how-to-create-yaml-dsl-route-in-apache-camel-to-query-ldap-properties

Comment: Thanks I created a ticket to not forget about this and to make it easier with jbang: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-19303